# Straight Join is not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an query related to straight join the query is correct but showing error

```
SELECT table112.id,table112.bval1,table112.bval2,  
table111.id,table111.aval1  
FROM table112  
STRAIGHT_JOIN table111;
```

Showing an error can anybody help out this

Comment: question why to use `straight_join`  ? are you aware that query optimizer chooses a poor query plan for straight_join ? why not use INNER JOIN instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is missing the join condition.

```
SELECT table112.id,table112.bval1,table112.bval2,
table111.id,table111.aval1
FROM table112
STRAIGHT_JOIN table111 ON table112.id = table111.id
```

Comment: It somewhat concerns me that the OP is using a straigh_join when he does not even know something this basic. This is an optimizing technique that should be used sparingly and only when necessary and probably never by anyone except an experienced dba.

Comment: Taken from the mysql documentation: STRAIGHT_JOIN is similar to JOIN, except that the left table is always read before the right table. This can be used for those (few) cases for which the join optimizer puts the tables in the wrong order.

Comment: Yes and that is why it is not something someone who is not an expert shoudl be using.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table112.id, table112.bval1, table112.bval2, table111.id,table111.aval1 FROM table112
```

That is not a join

```
Select * from table112 join table111 ON table112.id = table111.id
```

That is how a join works.

What are you trying to do? I might be able to help more than.